# Trying to get an Android WebView to zoom correctly

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to be able to display an image with zoom and scroll capabilities. Since this seems a bit too tedious with ImageView, I'm doing it with a WebView which loads the local image and then displays it. This is my current code:

```
    WebView image = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    image.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    image.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    image.setInitialScale(40);
    image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    image.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image.png");
```

While this loads the image, I can't get it to display only the image. There is always a decent amount of white space below it since setUseWideViewPort(true) makes it go all the way out to scale the width.

Any suggestions on allowing it to only scroll over the image that is loaded? Thanks. I've also tried setDefaultZoom and can't get it to go out far enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a static percentage 40 within your setInitialScale method is decent, however, it does not take into consideration screen density or size per say.  Currently your 40 means that you are scaled to 40% of the actual size.

Think about when you open up an image only in your web browser on your PC, this is going to essentially respond the same way, put it in the upper left corner.  Yes you can scale it with a WebView, but in this case to make it work for all platforms you are going to have to calculated your scaling factor based upon the screen resolution minus any bounding rectangle (top and bottom in the Android' case) related to the actual width and height of the image.

I suggest you go back to the ImageView!

Comment: Unfortunately, I just tried that and my image is too large to fit into memory. And I'm not going into the whole tiling feature to display this.

This should be way simpler.

Comment: Too large to fit into memory????  That doesn't even make any sense, when you bring it into the WebView, it is ALSO bringing the WHOLE image into memory, and actually making a copy of it to display it, just like an ImageView.  So what do you mean it is too big to fit in memory?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, I think that when you load a bitmap into an imageview, Android holds it in an uncompressed format. I don't think that Webview does that. Which is why it is able to fit into the WebView but not the ImageView.

Comment: You know, I just found this, and it may be just what you need.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947566/android-webview-or-imageview  This QA defines a very small amount of HTML in a string, and (essentially) inserts the filename to get into that said HTML.  The answer states to use the Width 100% attribute within HTML.  I think this should do what you want!!!  Based on the question, I think this supports my idea of how images are held and rendered within a WebView (i.e. should be the same as ImageView essentially).